# How to completely remove ubuntu from dual boot If I have installed using something else option(Manual partition)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I have installed ubuntu by Manual partition (something else option) and allocated around 80GB for Ubuntu, from it I have also created new efi system partition for ubuntu and 8 GB of swap area(As you can see in the image).
[image: Disk manager of my laptop]

In order to remove Ubuntu from my lap I have changed priority of boot first, after that I booted in to Windows. I have tried to delete spaces allocated for ubuntu, but delete option is not available for newly created EFI system partition. What can I do for deleting EFI system partition(which is created for ubuntu) in Disk 0.
[image]
Please help me to solve this issue.

I have installed ubuntu using this video - https://youtu.be/iSC0W0uJzB0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: I suspect you may have booted using that EFI partition or Windows has some sort of fail safe to prevent its deletion. One way to delete it would be to use your Ubuntu install media, choose try Ubuntu, not install Ubuntu and then use GParted to delete

Answer (score 0):

Delete all partitions except EFI system partition normally using delete option.
For deleting EFI system partition refer this video - https://youtu.be/NLOpLizFm3M